# Why this structure takes 24 bytes

Tags: c++, memory, types

```
    template<typename T>
    struct OctreeNode {
    std::variant<std::unique_ptr<OctreeNode<T>[]>, std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
    bool isLeaf;
    }
    sizeof(OctreeNode<int>)
```

I'm using x64 clang 10.
I thought it would take 8 bytes for variant and 8 for aligned boolean.

Comment: For a better question, explain _why_ you thought that. How did you come to that assessment? Cite your sources.

Comment: From cppreference: The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union.
std::unique_ptr uses as much memory as raw pointer. So i was not aware of std::variant state overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish between stored types `std::variant` contains an additional integral value that your calculation misses.

```
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct OctreeNode {
    std::variant<std::unique_ptr<OctreeNode<T>[]>, std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
    bool isLeaf;
};

template<typename T>
struct OctreeNodeAltVariant {
unsigned char index;
union {
    std::unique_ptr<OctreeNode<T>[]> a;
    std::unique_ptr<T> b;
};
};

template<typename T>
struct OctreeNodeAlt {
    OctreeNodeAltVariant<T> data;
    bool isLeaf;
};

static_assert(sizeof(OctreeNode<int>) == sizeof(OctreeNodeAlt<int>));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/UU_LP8